# Mysql таблица на 40-50 млн записей со множеством SELECT и INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, производительность, backend

Здраствуйте. Недавно на новом проекте столкнулся в первый раз с проблемой относительно больших данных в Mysql.

Если коротко то у нас есть почтовый прокси который принимает каждый запрос imap/pop3 (таких запросов примерно 20-30 в секунду) , проверяет пару вещей и передает запрос почтовому серверу перед этим записав в таблицу logs данные о запросе.

На каждый запрос есть один `SELECT COUNT (*) WHERE ip='ip запроса' ignore_for_ban=0 AND createdAt > "current timestamp - 1 hour"` и один `INSERT INTO logs` . Если count больше 10 за последний час, что бывает только в некоторых запросах, примерно раз в 15 мин то после него идет еще и `UPDATE logs SET ignore_for_ban = 1 WHERE ip='ip запроса' AND  createdAt > "current timestamp - 1 day"`. Это все работает но жрет очень много ресурсов. Подскажите как можно оптимизировать всё это дело ? какой выбрать mysql движок (пробовали innodb и aria) и какие столбцы разумней всего индексировать ? В крайнем случае посоветуйте альтернативы mysql.

*Далее структура таблицы logs*:

---

**id** PrimaryKey autoIncrement notNull

---

**username** VarChar notNull

---

**status** VarChar notNull

---

**ip** VarChar notNull

---

**continent** VarChar notNull

---

**country** VarChar notNull

---

**protocol** VarChar notNull

---

**domain** VarChar

---

**error_code** Integer

---

**error_message** VarChar

---

**destination_ip** VarChar

---

**destination_port** Integer

---

**ignore_for_ban** TinyInt

Comment: 1) Покажите точные тексты запросов. 2) Замените описание на результат `SHOW CREATE TABLE logs`.

Comment: На вскидку индекс должен быть (ip, createdAt). Интересно, зачем взводить флаг прямо в этой таблице и почему с глубиной на сутки назад, при том, что анализ идет с глубиной 1 час. А еще интересно по какому критерию принимается решение, что надо выдать запрос но конкретный ip

Comment: так ... не внимательно прочитал. с ip ясно "на каждый запрос" ... Тогда поставьте Redis. делаете в редисе incr по ключу ip. Ставите на ключ время жизни 1 час (после каждого обращения). Этот счетчик не такой как дает запрос в MySQL, т.к. сброситься в 0, только если за час не было ни одного запроса с ip. НО думаю что 90% записей будут сбрасываться. Если видите что счетчик превысил 10 - вот только после этого лезете в MySQL что бы получить действительно последний час

Comment: @Mike  Флаг в этой таблице нужен что бы посчитать количество failed запросов , но только определенного типа (ignore_for_ban зависит от причины по которой запрос прошел не успешно, записывается он на этапе создания строки в logs ) после которых определенный ip должен попасть в таблицу забаненных ip

Comment: @Mike идея с редис звучит неплохо

Comment: кстати при желании в redis можно класть не счетчик, а очередь из времени события. И тогда можно будет из начала этой очереди удалять значения, если они вышли за окно в 1 час. Но это возможно слишком хитрая логика будет и проще сделать счетчик, он по крайней мере достаточно сильно разгрузит mysql

Comment: @Mike я подумывал создать что то подобное в другой таблице того же Mysql , но учитывая что на этом сервере уже есть redis , почему бы и нет

Comment: @Akura точные тексты смогу опубликовать завтра когда доберусь до работы

Comment: @Mike в любом случае спасибо )

Comment: что касаеться самого MySQL и лога, я бы сделал страну char(2) а континент возможно убрал, так как зависит от страны. и посмотрел бы и на другие поля, нельзя ли их сократить. чем короче запись в таких больших таблицах - тем лучше

Comment: @Mike сегодня интегрировал редис , нагрузка упала

Comment: Если в первом запросе не нужно точное количество записей, а лишь факт превышения порога, можно поставить limit 11. Почему апдейт нужен на сутки? Судя по вашим данным, у вас в сутки 20-30 млн строк логов, и апдейт затрагивает пол таблицы за раз

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Спасибо всем за советы. В итоге я перенес всю логику бана в redis как посоветовал @Mike. Снизу предложенное им решение:

"так ... не внимательно прочитал. с ip ясно "на каждый запрос" ... Тогда поставьте Redis. делаете в редисе incr по ключу ip. Ставите на ключ время жизни 1 час (после каждого обращения). Этот счетчик не такой как дает запрос в MySQL, т.к. сброситься в 0, только если за час не было ни одного запроса с ip. НО думаю что 90% записей будут сбрасываться. Если видите что счетчик превысил 10 - вот только после этого лезете в MySQL что бы получить действительно последний час – Mike вчера"